# How do I add text to this CSS 'Switcher' 'Toggle Switch'

Tags: html

Here's the actual 'Swticher' Generator: https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

I'm not clear on how to add text to the event - so when the switch is on default certain text is shown and vica versa.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div class="onoffswitch">
      <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
          <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
      </label>
  </div>
```

I tried to add the class to a < p > tag but no joy.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste the css used by the site through DevTools. Anyways, what they do is, initially they set the checkbox to checked which makes the margin-left to be 0 which shows the ::before pseudo-element that has "ON" text. And on not checked, margin-left is set to -100% which shows ::after pseudo-element that has "OFF" text.

Here's the relevant CSS -

```
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-inner::before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner::after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
```

Here's the entire code in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0f4rbLmo/1/

Edit: 
If you want to toggle a div based on the switch, you can define hidden class like -

```
.triggeredDiv.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And then trigger it based on checkbox value in javascript when event is fired.

```
function toggleDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/g7qm2txs/

Comment: Thanks @Jason - but not sure if I understand. I thought (and tested) that if a <div> has the class of "ON" then only that content is show? What I am trying to do is trigger content (or content in a 'div') to be shown when the toggle is activated...

Comment: @henry So when "ON" is on, you want to show a div? If I understand you correctly, is this what you are expecting? I had to use javascript for this. I am sorry if I am still mistaken about your end goal. https://jsfiddle.net/g7qm2txs/