# Trying to show text using JavaScript and HTML/ CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a 'switcher' which currently has been styled and looks great.

What I would like is that when the switcher is swiped to the right then a DIV is printed on the page.

I can't find the error on the page...

Here's the CSS

```js
function toggleDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.triggeredDiv').classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener("change", toggleDiv);
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
        position: relative; width: 200px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner {
        display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 51px; padding: 0; line-height: 51px;
        font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before {
        content: "MONTHLY LIST";
        padding-left: 10px;
        background-color: #dfe4ea; color: #999999;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        content: "BY COUNTRY";
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #dfe4ea; color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch {
        display: block; width: 50px; margin: 0.5px;
        background: #A1A1A1;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 145px;
        border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
        right: 0px;
        background-color: #999999;
    }
    .triggeredDiv {
  display: block;
}

.triggeredDiv.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
     <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
      </div>

  <div class="triggeredDiv">
    Hello World
  </div>
```

The bit of the CSS that I believe 'hides' the CSS is here:

```
.triggeredDiv {
  display: block;
}

.triggeredDiv.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Can anyone see what it is that is wrong or missing?

This post was a previous precursor to [this request for help.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55203317)

By the way, the actual switcher generator is here: https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Comment: A DIV is printed on the page, So what is the error?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The DIV is appearing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I 'fixed' it by adding the JavaScript to the bottom of the page...I guess that is what was wrong - right?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: To put is very very simply, the script must be pleaced before the closing of the body tag since you wont be able to manipulate the DOM when the content loads after your script.